# RabbitMQ MQTT Plugin fail to start

Tags: plugins, centos, rabbitmq, mqtt

I am trying to configure RabbitMQ - MQTT plugin. But i cannot restart the service once enabled the plugin.

I followed the guide that i found on the docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html

To recap my actions:

I enabled the plugin with the command

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt
```

This is the response

```
[root@iot-rabbit01 rabbitmq]# rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt
The following plugins have been enabled:
  rabbitmq_mqtt

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@iot-rabbit01... failed.
Error: {could_not_start,rabbitmq_mqtt,
        {{shutdown,
          {failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_mqtt_listener_sup_:::1883',
           {shutdown,
            {failed_to_start_child,
             {ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}},
             {shutdown,
              {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
               {listen_error,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883},eacces}}}}}}},
         {rabbit_mqtt,start,[normal,[]]}}}
```

So i printed the enabled plugins list

```
[root@iot-rabbit01 rabbitmq]# rabbitmq-plugins list
 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status:   [failed to contact rabbit@iot-rabbit01 - status not shown]
 |/
[e ] amqp_client                       3.6.1
[  ] cowboy                            1.0.3
[  ] cowlib                            1.0.1
[e ] mochiweb                          2.13.0
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.6.1
[E ] rabbitmq_management               3.6.1
[e ] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.6.1
[E ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  1.2.1
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 0.1.0
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.6.1
[e ] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.6.1
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.6.1
[  ] sockjs                            0.3.4
[e ] webmachine                        1.10.3
```

As you can see the `[E ] rabbitmq_management 3.6.1` the plugin was explicitly enabled.

So i tried to start up the service

```
[root@iot-rabbit01 rabbitmq]# /sbin/service rabbitmq-server start
Starting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):                  [  OK  ]
```

It seems to be started correctly. But it is not.

```
[root@iot-rabbit01 rabbitmq]# rabbitmqctl status
Status of node 'rabbit@iot-rabbit01' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@iot-rabbit01': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@iot-rabbit01']

rabbit@iot-rabbit01:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on iot-rabbit01
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on iot-rabbit01
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-23@iot-rabbit01'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: pNNE23Tq7SUKunVAXkqReg==
```

This is what appears in the `startup_log`

```
         RabbitMQ 3.6.1. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@iot-rabbit01.log
  ######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@iot-rabbit01-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...

BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbitmq_mqtt,
       {{shutdown,
            {failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_mqtt_listener_sup_:::1883',
                {shutdown,
                    {failed_to_start_child,
                        {ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}},
                        {shutdown,
                            {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
                                {listen_error,
                                    {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883},
                                    eacces}}}}}}},
        {rabbit_mqtt,start,[normal,[]]}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@iot-rabbit01.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@iot-rabbit01-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbitmq_mqtt,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_mqtt_listener_sup_:::1883',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,{ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}},{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,{listen_error,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883},eacces}}}}}}},{rabbit_mqtt,start,[normal,[]]}}}}
```

This is the `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@iot-rabbit01.log` file

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Jan-2017::11:43:53 ===
Failed to start Ranch listener {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883} in ranch_tcp:listen([{port,
                                                                                       1883},
                                                                                      {ip,
                                                                                       {0,
                                                                                        0,
                                                                                        0,
                                                                                        0,
                                                                                        0,
                                                                                        0,
                                                                                        0,
                                                                                        0}},
                                                                                      inet6,
                                                                                      {backlog,
                                                                                       128},
                                                                                      {nodelay,
                                                                                       true}]) for reason eacces (permission denied)

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jan-2017::11:43:53 ===
stopped TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jan-2017::11:43:53 ===
Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbitmq_mqtt,
       {{shutdown,
            {failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_mqtt_listener_sup_:::1883',
                {shutdown,
                    {failed_to_start_child,
                        {ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}},
                        {shutdown,
                            {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
                                {listen_error,
                                    {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883},
                                    eacces}}}}}}},
        {rabbit_mqtt,start,[normal,[]]}}}
```

If you need more informations please contact me. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you checked that nothing is already running on port 1883? `sudo lsof -i -P -n` will show what ports are being used

Comment: Nothing is already running on 1883.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed my issue. For who will have my same issue.

> The plugin couldn't bind to port 1883 because the kernel responded
>   with the EACCESS error. Some kind of security tool (most likely
>   SELinux) needs that port to be whitelisted.

Changing SELinux parameters i was able to fix my issue. This is possible in two ways

1. Editing the file `/etc/selinux/config` editing the string `SELINUX=enforcing` into `SELINUX=permissive` or into (be careful, it's a security fault) `SELINUX=disabled`
2. Add the port 1883 with `semanage port --add` in the white list of SELinux

Comment: Got the same error on Windows, but didn't find any process that was listening to the same port. What helped was OS restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. An other mqtt broker was already running on the 1883 port…

Might help some who have this issue.